# MS-Graph API is returning Intermittent error with calendar event creation "ErrorIrresolvableConflict'

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

We have not made any changes to our application or method, but starting yesterday we began to see (again) the following intermittent error when trying to create events on any calendar using the Microsoft Graph API.

The error details are:

```
ErrorIrresolvableConflict

The send or update operation could not be performed because the 
change key passed in the request does not match the current change key for the item.
```

(Inner error detail omitted)

We previously experienced this in late Oct '19 through early Nov '19. And we noticed it again starting on 12/26/2019 and have experienced it today as well.

*Are there any resources for tracking the health or state of issues like this to see when they have been resolved? It would be awesome if there was some resource for tracking progress and resolution, and be able to provide guidance to our organization as it is being widely impacted by this issue again.

Any one have any other thoughts on how to work around this? We don't use a change key directly in our process - so think this must be an internal to Microsoft Error.

Thanks

Comment: Just an Update -  it still occurring today.  This is not a deletion, nor related to attachments. This is just from the initial event creation in our case.

Comment: It seems the issue has been fixed, please take a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58663396/getting-error-code-errorirresolvableconflict-responses-when-trying-to-create-e

Comment: Thanks, I just received confirmation directly from support at Microsoft as well that the fix for our tenancy was rolled out yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I am having this issue as well. I am calling a patch api on "Users" followed by a calendar create event. If there is a little delay between two calls then no issue otherwise getting 412. It's very sporadic.